# how does printf %n count characters?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int val;

  printf("blah%p%nblah", &val, &val);

  printf("val = %d\n", val);

  return 0;

}
```

This demo program is complied on 32-bit machine. I think `val` should be 8.
But I got this:

```
$ ./a.out
blah0xffa9b6fcblahval = 14
```

Why 14? `blah` is 4 chars. A pointer in IA32 should be 4 bytes. `%n` prints nothing.

Comment: Closing this as duplicate as the code seems to be taken from that answer, which in turn already answers this question.

Answer (score 3):

Please count the number of **printed** characters, they are 14.

The value stored in the variable `int` pointer the `"%n"` specifier is the number of characters **printed** prior to the occurrance of the `"%n"` specifier, there are 10 for the poitner address and 4 for `blah`.

```
blah0xffa9b6fc /* these are exactly 14 characters
  ^      ^
  %s     %p
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to support what [Mr. Iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208801/2173917),

Quoting from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()`, *(emphasis mine)*

> `n`
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is written **the
>   number of characters written to the output stream so far by this call** to
>   fprintf. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion
>   specification includes any flags, a field width, or a precision, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, it **does not** count the bytes in *format string*, rather, the *actual* printed bytes.

That said, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

This output string (before format specifier %n will be encountered)

```
blah0xffa9b6fc
```

contains exactly 14 symbols. The reason for val contains 14 is that format specifier `%p` outputs addresses in the hexadecimal notation

```
0xffa9b6fc
```

And indeed in your platform pointers have size of 4 bytes.:)